# How do I undo accidental svn update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-update

I accidently took an update of my project, and now the updated project has errors(due to partial commiting of code).

How can I undo the update process and get the working copy back.

The working copy contains packages that are from different revisions and I want it exactly as it was before the update.

Do i have to manually update my code package by package to its revision?

or is there any UNDO option??

**edit**: I dont want to correct the code in the server to working condition. I only need to find the revision of my local code(revision before the update) and revert my local code to that revision.

I am using **tortoise svn 1.7.9**

Comment: As far as I know, only stuff that's committed into the repository is protected by version control (and not all, e.g., revision properties themselves). Sorry.

Comment: i dont want to recover my uncommitted code. But i need to revert the files to the revision that was present before the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's nothing you can do to restore your working copy into its previous state, apart from doing it manually as you already mention.

Whatever, it isn't clear to me why your working copy contains a manually maintained list of files in older revisions. If those older files are required for current build, anyone else who checks out from the repository (including an automated build process) will systematically obtain the wrong files. Your repository actually lacks some information about current project version.

Is it possible that you actually want those packages somewhere else such as a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) or an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html), so that the HEAD revision contains automatically the required versions?

Comment: To silent downvoter: I'd really like to know why my answer is not useful, esp. considering that all other answers have been upvoted, including one that just repeats what the question already says (manually update). I'll be glad to edit or remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can revert the code to the stable revision and again commit that to keep svn head to stable version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"Update item to revision"** in the Svn client to Update to any specific revision(previous versions / older revisions).
If you have any local modified files that are merged during the update then, there is a chance of conflict.

Comment: How can i get the older version number for all files?

Comment: Go to the root directory, Usually this directory contains 'trunk', branchess etc.
Right click anywhere inside this root directory. click TortoiseSVN 
-> showlog to view the older revisions.
Then you can choose any revision.
right cick there and select update item to revision.